# Is it possible to make a glitch effect in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to do an effect like in the provided picture, where the screen would glitch at certain time intervals? Also, would it be possible if you have many thing going on in the screen(many separate moving parts such as shown below )

```
local ball
local background
local goal
local scoreTxt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a screen capture of the group, slice it up horizontally and then adjust the x positions slightly between each slice, but this would be a little CPU intensive.

To capture/save the screen:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/capture.html

To import the saved screenshot and slice it up:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/imageSheets/index.html

As for the greenish/purple linear effects, you might have to manually pre-create them for each object, and show them before you take a screen capture, then hide them right away.

Comment: what if I want to make it while an object is moving?

Comment: Well that is the point of the screenshots, you can move as many objects as you want in any direction, and the frame you want to use as a glitch, you would just capture what's on screen at the time.

Is this glitch effect going to happen during EVERY frame, or just once in a while? If it's every frame I don't know if this will work since it will kill your FPS, but if its say every few seconds, I don't see an issue on a decent device.

Comment: every few seconds, Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm having difficulty trying to find how to slice it up, I read the corona labs guide but still couldn't figure how to do it.